# Maintain date range when using sliderInput in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Diving into my first shinyApp...

I have 25 GPS locations at the bottom of the post, the `head` of which are below.  Dates are formatted `as.POSIXct`

```
head(dat)
  GPSUTMNorthing GPSUTMEasting             PosiGMT
1        4947787        600201 2013-02-09 00:00:00
2        4947945        600910 2013-02-09 06:00:00
5        4947957        600911 2013-02-10 00:00:00
6        4947954        600907 2013-02-10 06:00:00
8        4947797        601052 2013-02-10 18:00:00
9        4947835        601038 2013-02-11 00:00:00
```

The `UI` and `server` objects below can be used to make a `shinyApp` that plots the locations that correspond to the date selected on the `sliderInput`. Rather than plot only the locations from a specific date, I want to sequentially add locations as the date is moved forward on the `sliderInput`.  In this way the points from the first date are maintained as the the `sliderInput` is moved sequentially forward.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
          titlePanel("GPS Data Summary"),
          sliderInput(inputId = "Order",
                  label = "Sequance of Observations",  
                  min = as.Date(min(dat$PosiGMT)), max = as.Date(max(dat$PosiGMT)), value = as.Date(min(dat$PosiGMT))),
          plotOutput("PointPlot")
            )

server <- function(input, output) {
            output$PointPlot <- renderPlot({
              p <- ggplot(dat[as.Date(dat$PosiGMT) == input$Order ,], (aes(x = GPSUTMEasting , y = GPSUTMNorthing ))) + 
                geom_point() + geom_path() + 
                xlim( min(dat$GPSUTMEasting), max(dat$GPSUTMEasting))+
                ylim( min(dat$GPSUTMNorthing), max(dat$GPSUTMNorthing))
              print(p)
              })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Reproducible data below

```
dat <- structure(list(GPSUTMNorthing = c(4947787L, 4947945L, 4947957L, 
    4947954L, 4947797L, 4947835L, 4947825L, 4947784L, 4947842L, 4947839L, 
    4947789L, 4947807L, 4947839L, 4947845L, 4947779L, 4947824L, 4947824L, 
    4947772L, 4947824L, 4947821L, 4947816L, 4947809L, 4947840L, 4947829L, 
    4947820L), GPSUTMEasting = c(600201L, 600910L, 600911L, 600907L, 
    601052L, 601038L, 601031L, 601066L, 600998L, 600995L, 601058L, 
    601038L, 600987L, 601071L, 601016L, 601002L, 601003L, 601003L, 
    600917L, 600916L, 600918L, 600923L, 600985L, 600980L, 600914L
    ), PosiGMT = structure(c(1360393200, 1360414800, 1360479600, 
    1360501200, 1360544400, 1360566000, 1360587600, 1360630800, 1360652400, 
    1360674000, 1360695600, 1360717200, 1360738800, 1360803600, 1360825200, 
    1360846800, 1360868400, 1360890000, 1360911600, 1360933200, 1360954800, 
    1360976400, 1360998000, 1361019600, 1361041200), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("GPSUTMNorthing", "GPSUTMEasting", 
    "PosiGMT"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 
    14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
    29L, 30L, 31L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it, this is not a shiny issue but a subsetting one.

Change:

`ggplot(dat[as.Date(dat$PosiGMT) == input$Order ,]`

to

`ggplot(dat[as.Date(dat$PosiGMT) <= input$Order ,]`

I think this is the behaviour you want

Comment: Perfect.  Very helpful.  Of course, I was not thinking through the reactive nature of `shiny` with my data subset. Much appreciated!